# How to create a ToolStripItem?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net

I have ToolStripContainer I need to add the child to be his element. Just can drag and drop as usual ToolStripItems
Element is simply a ListBox.

[image]

.net framework 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can drag MenuStrip, StatusStrip and ToolStrip into ToolStripContainer. You can find them in All Forms or Menus&Toolbars section.

Comment: Yes, but i need my control with ListBox

Comment: So why are using ToolStipContainer?? It is for containing strips, such MenuStrip, no for ToolStripItems...

Comment: Explain, I do not understand. I do not know much English.

Comment: I don't understand your question. I don't see connection beetwen ToolSripContainer, ToolStripItem and ListBox. You should edit your question to be more clear...